# Constraint Layout to stretch to edge of the screen

Tags: android, xml, android-constraintlayout

[here is the image of the pic i want without the space on the right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZCvxW.png)I have a nested constraint layout.
I am trying to use a `drawable` as a background for my constraint layout. The only problem is that it does not stretches to the edges of the screen. what I want is to have the `drawable` on the edge of the screen so that it can be a part of the edge of the screen.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/img_bg"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"

        android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
        android:translationZ="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/innter_constraint"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/innter_constraint"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/barrier"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_btn_enter" />


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="of spa booking"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_termsandconditions">

    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_termsandconditions"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="102dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/terms_and_condititons"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageButton"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.736" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Barrier
        android:id="@+id/barrier"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"

        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:barrierDirection="bottom"
        app:constraint_referenced_ids="innter_constraint"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="437dp">

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Barrier>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/innter_constraint"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:alpha="0.5"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_img_bg"

        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="40dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.51"

        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/guideline_vertical"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline_vertical"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.499">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"


            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="(+91)Enter the mobile number"
            android:inputType="phone"
            android:textSize="16sp"

            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView" />


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="16dp"
            android:layout_height="16dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_icon_phone"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/editText"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/editText" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/not_verify_short"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="16dp"
            android:text="Hello,"
            android:textColor="@color/colorViews"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/editText"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Barrier
            android:id="@+id/barrier2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="20dp"
            app:barrierDirection="bottom"
            app:constraint_referenced_ids="editText" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline_vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.2" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

as you can see I really don't want the space that is out there and need to just stick it to the right edge of the screen. How can I make sure that it is `scalable` in all the phones. I used padding but it goes off the screen and is not a recommended practice. What constraint should I add to fill my space on the right side of the screen with the `drawable` background.

Comment: you shouldn't use both left and start constraints. when on LTR direction just use start instead of left and end instead of right. Also, I don't understand the need for the nested layout. Constraint layout is meant to be flat. Furthermore, you're setting the left constraint twice to two different views.

Comment: I need to have a custom drawable layout you see those borders inside the constraint layout.

Comment: when you reference a view in your constraints use @id/ instead of @+id/. The latter is used when you create a view for the first time and you want to give it a unique id. If you remove the bias and set your top, bottom, start and end constraints, while referencing the parent as the end constraint for your nested layout and having its width as 0dp, it should work.

Comment: for the record, I replaced the drawables with plain colours and it works. If you apply the changes suggested and you still find it that it doesn't work, then the space created comes from your drawable and not the constraints.

Comment: the reason I'm using drawable is I have rounded edges.yeah it just worked Thanks

Comment: I don't suggest you remove it, I'm just saying that because I don't have your drawables, when I tested your code I just replaced them with standard colours and I was able to get the desired effect. So if it's indeed the case that your drawable is adding the extra space, you might need to edit that instead of your constraints.

Comment: Is it possible to not to use two constraint layout in this case? Can I achieve the same result by just one constraint layout?

Comment: My understanding is that you only use the nested layout to define a smaller area that has a different background. If you wanted a flat design you could use an imageview instead with the desired background drawable

Comment: Yeah. That's exactly. Just because of that small area I had too much of problem.